# How to make a Scanner user input correspond to an if statement

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, string-comparison

So here's what I have right now. I am trying to get the user inputted answer to correspond with my if statements. Right now It will not give me anything it asks for my input then the program just stops it does not give me any out put or errors. I feel like I'm close, can anyone assist?

**EDIT: So a lot of you are trying to help me with the while loop, that is not the part I am trying to fix. I am trying to figure out what I am missing in the if(contract.equals("A")) and why that won't give me any output based on that, I can figure out the while loop, I just can't get it to if you enter A it will not run the A selection. what am I missing?**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BillCalculator{

      public static void main(String[]args)
       {
          double totalBill;
          double rate;
          double baseCharge;
          double hours;
          double allowedHours;
          double extra=0;
          String contract;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("What package did you purchase?");
      contract= keyboard.nextLine();

      System.out.println("How many hours did you use?");
      hours=keyboard.nextDouble();


      if (contract.equals("A"))
       {
        baseCharge=9.95;
        rate=2.00;
        allowedHours=10;
        while (hours>allowedHours)
          {
           extra=extra+1;
          }
        totalBill=baseCharge+(rate*extra);
        System.out.println("Your total bill is "+ totalBill);
       }
    else if (contract.equals("B"))
      {
        baseCharge =13.95;
        rate=1.00; 
        totalBill=baseCharge+(rate*(hours-20));
        System.out.println("Your total bill is "+ totalBill);
      }
   else if (contract.equals("C"))
      {
      System.out.println("Total monthly bill is $19.95.");
      }
   else 
    System.out.println("Wrong input."); 

  }

}
```

Comment: Likely the while loop never stops. `while (hours>allowedHours)` -> you should modify `hours` inside the loop, otherwise that condition will always be true and you'll end up having an infinite loop.

Comment: see your `while` loop: It's an infinite loop since you have no exit condition in place (i.e. `extra` is incremented, but the condition uses `hours` instead)

Comment: You should learn to tell the difference between a program that stops and one that hangs. The first one brings you back to the command line (or the IDE shows it's finished) and the second one keeps running without producing any output. As others have pointed out, your program doesn't stop; it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop inside

```
 if (contract.equals("A"))
   {
    baseCharge=9.95;
    rate=2.00;
    allowedHours=10;
    while (hours>allowedHours)
      {
       extra=extra+1;
      }
    totalBill=baseCharge+(rate*extra);
    System.out.println("Your total bill is "+ totalBill);
   }
```

is infinite while hours attribute input > 10

If you want to fix it I recommend you to **update your while condition** or check something with an if statement (then a break) within the while loop

I also recommend you to display your input errors like this

```
System.err.println("Wrong input.");
```

Comment: Or update either `hours` or `allowedHours` in the loop. But I guess `hours -
 extra > allowedHours` should be enough to get the extra hours. Carefull with `System.err` if you are using both `System.out` and `System.err` in a processing. The output are not necessarily synchronize so the output message could be printed in console in a different order.